# HTML Data Parsing using Python

Tags: python, html

I tried to scrape the web content using the Python i got the below response

```
     <TD class="title_1" align="right" >

               type of accidentLABUTYP：<br>

    <input type="button" name="11" value="Choice picture" onclick="popBztp('sglx','imgsglx','1')" class="imagesbutton">

    &nbsp;

    <input type="hidden" name="sglx" value="33">

  </TD>

    <TD class="item_1"  >

   &nbsp;<IMG   id="imgsglx" onerror="this.alt='not select the picture or    pictures cannot be displayed'"  style=" border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;height:110px;width:110px; "    src="http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/sglx_images/LABUTYP/308.jpg"  />

  &nbsp;

  </TD>

   <TD class="title_1" align="right" >

       type of accidentUTYP：<br>

        <input type="button" name="11" value="Choice picture" onclick="popBztp('sglx2','imgsglx2','2')" class="imagesbutton">

    &nbsp;

        <input type="hidden" name="sglx2" value="140">

   </TD>

   <TD class="item_1"  >

       &nbsp;                               

     <IMG   id="imgsglx2" onerror="this.alt='not select the picture or pictures cannot be displayed'"  style=" border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;height:110px;width:110px; " src="http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/sglx_images/UTYP/221.jpg"  />

 &nbsp;
 </TD>
```

from the above i would like to get the info
"http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/sglx_images/UTYP/221.jpg"

Please help me how can i do this with python. any help on how to parse the html content to get all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

This is the link for HTMLParser built in python.

Or you can see your HTML as a txt file simply parsing it looking for your string:

```
if 'http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/sglx_images/UTYP/221.jpg' in open('example.html').read():
    print "true"
```

---

### Edit1

You could use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc)

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.url.com"))
page.findAll('img')
```

Comment: Hi, Here i added the sample. i have the big html text and i want to parse and get some information. and it may not be same as "http://114.255.167.200:8092/cidasEN/extend/sglx_images/UTYP/221.jpg" always. but other tags and structure will be same. i have to get the info based on the tags.

Comment: I've added a simple tool to achieve this tell me if is ok.